Spring Session / Security - Redis Sessions not being properly deleted
I have a Spring OAuth Client (BFF), between a Public Angular Client, and an Auth0 Authorization server. When I login, the BFF correctly persists the session to Redis (and with it, the Authorized Client, Security Context, and Authorized Request as attributes in the session)
When I logout though, only the contents of the Session get deleted, the key itself does not. Also nothing in the Sorted Set, ever gets deleted.
Logout Handler
Here is my Logout Handler
@Component
internal class SessionServerLogoutHandler(
    private val sessionControl: SessionControl,
    private val sessionProperties: SessionProperties,
    private val csrfProperties: CsrfProperties,
) : ServerLogoutHandler {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionServerLogoutHandler::class.java)

    override fun logout(exchange: WebFilterExchange, authentication: Authentication?): Mono<Void> {
        return exchange.exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                logger.info("Logging out: Invalidating User Session: ${session.id}")

                val response = exchange.exchange.response
                sessionControl.invalidateSession(session)
                    .then(Mono.fromRunnable {

                        logger.info("Deleting Session Cookie: ${sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME}")

                        // delete the session cookie
                        val sessionCookie = ResponseCookie.from(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
                        sessionCookie.maxAge(0)
                        sessionCookie.httpOnly(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY)
                        sessionCookie.secure(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE)
                        sessionCookie.sameSite(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE)
                        sessionCookie.path(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH)
                        sessionCookie.domain(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
                        .build()
                        response.headers.add(
                            HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                            sessionCookie.toString()
                        )

                        logger.info("Deleting Session Cookie: ${csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME}")

                        // delete the CSRF cookie
                        val csrfCookie = ResponseCookie.from(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME)
                        csrfCookie.maxAge(0)
                        csrfCookie.httpOnly(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY)
                        csrfCookie.secure(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE)
                        csrfCookie.sameSite(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_SAME_SITE)
                        csrfCookie.path(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_PATH)
                        csrfCookie.domain(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
                        .build()
                        response.headers.add(
                            HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                            csrfCookie.toString()
                        )
                    })
            }
    }
}

SessionControl
It calls another class called SessionControl, and the invalidate session method. Here is that function
fun invalidateSession(session: WebSession): Mono<Void> {
        val sessionInformation = getSessionInformation(session)
        logger.info("Invalidating sessionId: ${sessionInformation.sessionId}")
        // handle the session invalidation process
        return sessionInformation.invalidate()
            .then(Mono.defer {
                webSessionStore.removeSession(sessionInformation.sessionId)
            })
            .doOnSuccess {
                logger.info("Session invalidated and removed: ${sessionInformation.sessionId}")
            }
            .doOnError { error ->
                logger.error("Error invalidating session: ${sessionInformation.sessionId}", error)
            }
    }

WebSessionStore
That inturn calls Websession Store, and it's removeSession method.
Here is the bean and the function:
@Bean(name = ["webSessionStore"])
fun webSessionStore(
    reactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository: ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository
): SpringSessionWebSessionStore<RedisSession> {
    return SpringSessionWebSessionStore(reactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository)
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> removeSession(String sessionId) {
    return this.sessions.deleteById(sessionId);
}

reactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository
The this.sessions above refers to the ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository that was passed in the constructor of the WebsessionStore. Looking at the internals of the Spring ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository I see this:
public Mono<Void> deleteById(String id) {
        return deleteAndReturn(id).then();
    }

    private Mono<RedisSession> deleteAndReturn(String id) {
        // @formatter:off
        return getSession(id, true)
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getExpiredKey(session.getId()))
                        .thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getSessionKey(session.getId())).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.indexer.delete(session.getId()).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.expirationStore.remove(session.getId()).thenReturn(session));
        // @formatter:on
    }

Session in Redis before
As you can see before I logout, the session is there in Redis.

Session in Redis after
After I call the logout handler, something has definitely happened, but the session is still there with its key, just no map of values apart from a single lastaccessed map key / value.

Further more nothing ever gets deleted from the SortedSet, which according to the 4th step in the deleteAndReturn method above, it should...

So, can someone help me understand where I may have gone wrong in my code?

Let's look into deleteAndReturn:
    private Mono<RedisSession> deleteAndReturn(String id) {
        // @formatter:off
        return getSession(id, true)
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getExpiredKey(session.getId()))
                        .thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getSessionKey(session.getId())).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.indexer.delete(session.getId()).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.expirationStore.remove(session.getId()).thenReturn(session));
        // @formatter:on
    }

You receive an id, but you almost completely ignore it. Instead, you attempt to get the id from the session via session.getId(), but the session has already been invalidated. Instead, you will need to use and pass id instead of session.getId().

True, but doesn’t the first step get expired id, and the second get session id… I wonder why Spring would design their own class implementation this way?

@Sachin since I did not implement or plan it, so I cannot answer this question. Yet, sessionInformation.invalidate() is invalidating your session so you need to get its id before you invalidate it. Did the suggestion work? If so, you may consider accepting it as the correct solution.

I removed invalidate complete, and just used removesession, but that doesn' resolve the problem. The session still exists with its key, and the lastaccessedtime value - but it's not the final answer

@Sachin have you refactored deleteAndReturn?

No, that is the default Spring implementation in a read only class. But I removed invalidate() to test your hypothesis. The Redis key though is still there and does not get deleted. I also tried using ReactiveRedisIndexedRepository.RedisOperations.delete(sessionId) directly, that that didn't work at all

@Sachin so you have sessionInformation.then(...) in your test currently?

Yes in my SessionControl class, I have the line:  return sessionInformation.... (write some reactive code)...

@Sachin understood. Did you try debugging deleteAndReturn? Does it internally understand what the session id is?

It must do. If you look at the function, all it wants is a string (the session id), then it uses that to run the four internal steps. But the Spring team will know more about why they've implemented it that way.

@Sachin you still need to test it to make sure you rely on verified facts rather than hypotheses. If it correctly identifies the session id, then you will need to actively remove the now unnecessary items. If it does not recognize it, then you have a problem calling it.

ok, i will try to create a local implementaiton of it.
